# Facebook post from winforms app

Tags: c#, facebook

I have setup a business account with Facebook and got my access token. Then I try and use the below code inside my WinForms App and it all passes through fine with now errors, but when I go to my Facebook page nothing has been posted to it, is there something simple I am missing here?

```
string acccessToken = <access token>;
FacebookClient appp = new FacebookClient(acccessToken);
try
{
    appp.PostAsync("10000xxxxxx6328/feed", 
                    new { message = "Good Morning To Me" });
}
catch (FacebookOAuthException)
{

}
```

Any pushes in the right direct would be great.

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: did you set a breakpoint or anything to make sure it's not going into the catch

Comment: Hi, yes I did make sure it went through. By the sounds of that you expected it to fail :)